# Correct way to use button navigation in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a project in React, and one of the last things I want to do is use buttons on the homepage to navigate to a Map component and change the starting location. So essentially on the homepage a user would click 'Washington, DC' and it would route to my /map and also pass the map starting coordinates for DC. I my question is what would be the most proper way to do this? My current code, that doesn't work as I'm still debating the architecture of this, looks like:

```
   <button
     className="tourButtons"
     onClick={() => {
       <Route exact path="/home" render={ (washington) =>
          <Map {...washington} />
       }/>
     }}
    >
    Washington, DC
   </button>
```

My Map is a functional component that has a default center if you load via a different button. Relevant parts of that code should only be:
`const center = { lat: 39.7459467, lng: -75.5465889, };`
and
`<GoogleMap center={center}>`

My router in /App currently looks like (added homepage last, eventually changing that route around so home is at / and map is at /map)

```
 <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/home" component={Home}></Route>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Map}></Route>
      <Route exact path="/suggest" component={Form}></Route>
 </Switch>
```

Ramblings on what resources and ideas I've come up with so far include:

- I shouldn't be using a route in my onClick as that is giving me a "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions" error
- looked at https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105 and https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props which lead me to believe I need to make changes to my router in /App to accommodate passing data
- maybe I need to use the url to accomplish this, something like website.com/map/:center?

I feel like this question is trivial, but am asking so I can form good habits going forward. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new `<Route/>` on the `/App`. You can pass the props down to `Map` as needed.

```
<Route
    path='/map'
    render={(props) =>
        <Map
            {...props}
            coords={this.state.coords}
        />
    }
/>
```

Since you are on the `Home` component, you probably need to pass a function from `App` down to `Home` via prop so you can update the, for example, coords state on the `App` which you will be passing as prop down to `Map`. Example code on App:

```
updateCoords = (val) => {
    this.setState({
        coords: val
    })
}

<Route
    path='/home'
    render={(props) =>
        <Home
            {...props}
            updateCoords={this.updateCoords}
        />
    }
/>
```

Then on `Home` simply call `this.props.updateCoords(someValue)` to update the state of the coords state on your `App`.

If you need to redirect right away I suggest using the `<Link>` (https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) or use history api on `App`

```
this.props.history.push(`/${someRoute}`);
```

Comment: <Link> is exactly what I was looking for, just have to change the styling around to make it span like a button. I then added (props) to my functional component and called it in my google maps wrapper.